# How is this definition of closedness compatible with the order topology?

Tags: set-theory, order-topology

Let $\kappa$ be a limit ordinal.
Taken from the definition of a *closed unbounded* set,
we say a subset $C\subseteq\kappa$ is *closed* in $\kappa$ if and only if

> $\sup(C\cap\alpha)=\alpha<\kappa\implies\alpha\in C$

Is this definition equivalent to being closed with respect to the *order topology* on $\kappa$?
[Wikipedia claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Club_set) it should be, but I cannot prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order topology has as its sub-base all upper and lower sets, $U(\alpha) = \{\beta: \beta > \alpha\}$ and $L(\alpha) = \{\beta: \beta < \alpha\}$.

This implies that in an ordinal $\kappa$, all successor ordinals $\alpha+1\in \kappa$ are isolated points, because $\{\alpha+1\}= (\alpha, \alpha+2)=U(\alpha\} \cap L(\alpha+2)$.
At limit ordinals $\beta\in \kappa$  we have that a local base is all
sets of the form $(\alpha, \beta]$ (this is open as $U(\alpha)\cap L(\beta+1)$), so at limit ordinals the topology "looks to the left".

Now suppose that $C$ is order-closed and that $\sup(C\cap \alpha) = \alpha < \kappa$ and $\alpha$ is a limit. Then if $(\gamma, \beta]$ is any basic open neighbourhood of $\alpha$, with some $\gamma < \alpha$, we note that $\gamma$ is no upperbound for $C\cap \alpha$ and so some $\gamma'\in C\cap \alpha$ exists with $\gamma' > \gamma$. This means that $\gamma' \in (\gamma, \alpha]$ so that we know that every basic neighbourhood of $\alpha$ intersects $C$, so $\alpha \in \overline{C}=C$, as required.

A similar argument shows that if $C$ obeys the "$\sup$-property", it is order closed: let $\alpha \in \overline{C}$. If $\alpha$ is isolated it has a neighbourhood $\{\alpha\}$ that must intersect $C$, so $\alpha \in C$. So now assume $\alpha$ is a limit. $\alpha \in \overline{C}$ implies that for every $\gamma < \alpha$ the basic neighbourhood $(\gamma, \alpha]$ intersects $C$. This readily implies that $\alpha = \sup(C \cap \alpha)$ (as $\alpha$ is surely an upperbound for $C \cap \alpha$ and the previous remarks shows no smaller one can exist. The property then implies $\alpha \in C$ and so $\overline{C} \subseteq C$ and $C$ is order-closed.

Comment: Unfortunately, my edit got rejected, so I am writing this in a comment because it took me some while to realise it. You are using these two statements from general topology:

1. $C$ is closed if and only if $\overline{C}\subseteq C$, and
2. $\alpha\in\overline{C}$ if and only if every open neighbourhood of $\alpha$ intersects $C$

Comment: @Lilalas Indeed, that’s what I use. It’s pretty elementary I’d say, topology 101.